# ExpressJS receive JSON string but missing some part

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I use Ajax with JSON method to send base64 image string to ExpressJS. The whole JSON use `console.log` to display in client web browser is correct before sending into ExpressJS.

The whole JSON string I cannot show in here due to the length limitation. But the result is similar to the following output:

```
{"map":"base64 String", "other":"abcdefghij"}
```

The ExpressJS most of the time can receive the whole JSON string. But sometimes the result like the following:

```
ng", "other":"abcdefghij"}
```

OR

```
{"map":"base64 Strin
```

**UPDATE:**

Client upload JSON to server:

```
$('#btn_floor_upload').click(function () {
    var map_image_obj = new Image();
    map_image_obj.src = URL.createObjectURL($('#select_map_file').prop('files')[0]);
    $(map_image_obj).one('load', function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.height = window.canvas_height;
        canvas.width = window.canvas_width;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(map_image_obj, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // above action for resizing image

        var upload_data = {
            map: canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.2),
            height: window.canvas_height,
            width: window.canvas_width,
            floor_name: $('#floor_name').val()
        };


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/edit/upload_floor",
            data: JSON.stringify(upload_data),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "JSON",
            timeout: 3000,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.uploaded) {
                    $('#floor_list').append(new Option($('#floor_name').val(), result.floor_id));
                    $('#floor_name').val("");
                    $('#select_map_file').val("");
                    $('#btn_delete_floor').attr("disabled", false);
                    $('#floor_dialog').modal('toggle');
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                $.notify({
                    message: 'Server Error, Please upload the image again!'
                }, {
                    type: 'danger',
                    delay: '5000'
                });
                $('#floor_dialog').modal('toggle');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Server side:
The error occur in line 4.

```
upload_floor(req, res){
    req.on('data', function(data) {
        try {
            var json = JSON.parse(data.toString());
            var floor_id = buildingFloor.upload_map(json.floor_name, json.map, json.height, json.width, req.session.username);
            res.send(JSON.stringify({floor_id: floor_id, uploaded:true}));
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
};
```

Error Message:

```
Unexpected token m in JSON at position 1
```

OR

```
Unexpected end of JSON input sometimes
```

Comment: SinLok, Have you tried to stringify the json from the express server and parse at the client.

Comment: @Vishnudev The base64 image string is sent from client to server. Not server to client. I use JSON.stringify before the sending action. But the whole string display in the web browser is correct.

Comment: You might need to show how you read input JSON on the server side

Comment: Could you post the AJAX part of the client code where it is posted to the server?

Comment: @Vishnudev Please see my update section.

Comment: @SinLok Whats the size of the image sent to the server?

Comment: This should most probably be the problem. [LIMIT OF REQUEST BODY SIZE](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#limit-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `req.on('data')` doesn't (always) receive all the data at once.

The correct code would be:

```
let raw = ''

req.on('data', function(data) {
  raw += data
})

req.on('end', function() {
  // so something with `raw` here
})
```

But to use `req.on` directly is rather low-level, you can probably just use body-parser to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

try writing this way-
{"map":"base64 String", "other":"abcdefghij"}

Comment: Sorry. Maybe my explanation is not clear. I have already used JSON.stringify.